# Duvida com o %i

Tags: c

Sei que com o `%i` pode se ler números na base decimal, hexadecimal, e octal, mas quando eu digito 0x15, aparece o número 21, sendo que era quinze que era aparecer ou estou enganado?

Exemplo abaixo

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int n = 0x15;
   printf("%d\n",n);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0x15 em hexa = 21 em decimal.

Os especificadores `%i` e `%d` são interpretados da mesma maneira pelas funções da família `fprintf()`, mas são interpretados de forma diferente pela família de funções do `fscanf()`.

Utilizar `%d` implica que o valor digitado pelo usuário será interpretado como um número inteiro decimal.

Utilizar `%i` permite o usuário informar valores na base de 8, 10 e 16.

Quando você digita o `printf` você utiliza `%d`, portanto o resultado foi em decimal.

Comment: Obrigado @Leticia Rosa